# Java .class file size Vs .java file size

Tags: java

I made a simple java file :

```
class Hello {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The size of this hello.java file is **87 bytes** while the class file size is **401 bytes**

I have to ask what things get add to code so that class file has large size ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: And you can run javap -p plus some other options I don't know by heart to see the class fully de-assembled

Comment: The first thing you should do is compare apples to apples by fully writing out all of the things that the compiler fills in for you: (1) explicitly declare `extends java.lang.Object` (2) explicitly include the no-arg constructor (3) fully qualify all references (e.g. `java.lang.String`) (4) The bytecode also includes the full class name and signature of any method call, so add some casts to the method call: `((java.io.PrintStream)System.out).println((java.lang.String)"Hello");` (5) explicitly use `return`, both in the method call and constructor call. With all that, your file grows to ~200b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to ask what things get add to code so that class file has large size ?

Your question is founded on a fallacy. The source code isn't in the .class file, so nothing is 'added'. However a large amount of stuff is *compiled* into the .class file:

1. A .class file header, including Java version information, the class and package names, the superclass, the implemented interfaces, the constant pool size and data, the field count and fields, the method count and methods, attribute count and attributes, etc.
2. A method area containing the bytecode.

For details see the [JVM Specification #4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html).